# How to initialize a variable using another variable in an SKScene

Tags: swift, variables, sprite-kit, skscene

I want to be able to make two variables available to the entire `SKScene`, and all functions inside of it. One of these variable using the other one to create its value. I understand why I cannot do this, but I don't know a fix for it. I have this code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let num : CGFloat = 1.25
    let reciprocal = 1 / num          //   <— This Line

    override func sceneDidLoad() {

    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered

    }

}
```

But I am obviously getting an error the line 4.

> Cannot use instance member 'num' within property initializer; property
>   initializers run before 'self' is available

This means that I cannot use the variable because it is connected to the skscene, and the scene hasn't been implemented fully yet. Is there a way to declare this variable without throwing an error and making it assessable everywhere within this class?

Comment: what is the error message and `recip`?

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil I updated it with the error. `recip` just finds the reciprocal of the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `reciprocal` depends directly upon `num`, it could make sense to let the prior be a computed property based on the latter

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let num: CGFloat = 1.5
    var reciprocal: CGFloat { return 1/self.num }

    // ...

}
```

Since `num` is an immutable property and will never change at runtime, another alternative is to let `reciprocal` be a `lazy` variable, computed upon its first use

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let num: CGFloat = 1.5
    lazy var reciprocal: CGFloat = { return 1/self.num }()

    // ...

}
```

(Or, implement your own custom initializer for the `GameScene`, where you can initialize `num` and `reciprocal` to e.g. a given value and its reciprocal, respectively).

Comment: now I am getting this error: Instance member 'num' cannot be used on type 'GameScene'

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 my bad, forget the `self.`; try the updated answer.

Comment: I tried the `lazy var` way before. I had no luck, still doesn't work. When I try the original method I get this error: Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> GameScene' has no member 'num'

Comment: I changed the reciprocal and took away the function, because I felt that it was useless, hopefully this makes it easier to find a fix

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 Both the above work fine for me. Are you sure you've tried the above using the same syntax as in the two examples? (/what version of Swift are you using?)

Comment: my bad, I had typed it in wrong. This works thanks a lot :)

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 happy to help! Just note that final note in my answer: if you use a custom initializer, that is probably the best spot to initialize `num` and `reciprocal` as two immutables.

Comment: thank you, I hadn't thought of that one, now I feel that was kind of obvious. I will most likely use the custom initializer. Thanks for your help